# Wheather to implement crud or cms for a restaurant website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, crud

I am thinking of doing a website for a small local restaurant to build my portfolio.
I am in the process of planning out what functionality there would be and the first thing was the menu page. I would like the restaurant owners to be able to sign in and make changes to menu like prices, description and items. I have also been using rails gem devise to use authentication so I was thinking of making an admin account so that they can log in and make the changes. Does it sound like an okay plan? If not, whats the best route? And will CMS like Refinery and Spina also achieve the same objective like crud?